# Zapier - how to process all entries of an array?

Tags: zapier

In a custom integration, made with Zapier Platform UI, a Search Action returns an array. Can Zapier process every item in that array with the following steps in the same Zap?

The Search Action takes a Lead ID in a CRM (AmoCRM), and returns an array [{id:123},{id:456}] of contacts associated to that lead. In the following steps I would like to get details for those contacts (email, name), and write that into a contacts repository (an email platform).

If I build the zap in a straightforward way, I see that only the first entry of the array is processed. Is there a way to process every entry in the array?

I described the problem in more details here: https://community.zapier.com/developer-discussion-13/processing-an-array-of-contacts-from-a-single-crm-lead-1400

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I found a workaround, assuming that I didn't miss anything and Zapier itself indeed only processes the first element of the array.

It's like this. For each contact in the array I fire a webhook (in the Action code) with that id in the payload. Then I make a separate Zap that catches the webhook and processes it.